# Change the selection field value on calling onchange function of other field in openerp

Tags: python, odoo

I have been working on an OpenERP module . The scenario is that I have a selection field containing categories of some assets.  I have another field and its associated with an onchange function . Now I want is when my onchange function gets called , the selection field value dynamically set with one of its dropdown values. The selection field is "asset_type" and the other field is "categ_temp2". I tried with the following technique but it didnot work.

```
<field name="categ_temp2" domain="[('parent_id', '!=', False)]" on_change="mmProduct_Category_OnChange(categ_temp2,asset_type)"/>

def mmProduct_Category_OnChange(self,cr,uid,ids,categ_temp2,asset_type):
    for id in ids: 
             emp = self.pool.get('product.product')
             emp.write(cr,uid,ids,{'asset_type', '=', 'phones'})
```

Plz point my mistake or guide me to solve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it using the following syntax in my Python code:

```
  def myProduct_Category_OnChange(self,cr,uid,ids,categ_temps):
        pro_id=[]
        if (str(categ_temps)=='3'):
            return {'value':{'asset_type': 'phones'}}
```

'3' is the id of the categories which is set on the first field (i.e categ_temps)
  By doing this, tha value in the asset_type is selected dynamically when 'catge_temps' is set to id:3